# Exiting the method/process without calling exit() method

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, exit

I am writing an android application where I use a C code as a library through JNI. I start the library as a separate thread as shown below.

```
    public class LibraryHandler implements Runnable {
        private static final String TAG = "LibraryHandler";
        @Override
        public void run() {
                Log.w(TAG, "Starting library");
                testJNILib.startlibrary();
        Log.e(TAG, "Bounced out of library Handler loop. Exiting....");
      }
    }
```

and I stop the thread by interrupting it when my application closes and assign it to null.

But the method doesnt library when the thread stops as it runs coitnuuosly and only stops when I terminate it manually using the "stoplibary()" call. But when I call the stoplibrary call, it calls exit() function and therefore shuts down the whole app. I want to stop only the library and not the entire process. I have to clean up all the resources so I just can't use return instead of exit(). CAn someone please let me know any approach that I can follow to clean up all the resources instead of exit.

The "startLibrary()" & "stoplibrary()" goes to the JNI as shown

```
    extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_android_client_testJNILib_startlibrary(JNIEnv * je, jclass jc)
{
   char *argv[] = {"libproxyd", "-o", "unix:/data/data/com.adaranet.android.droidproxyclient2/files/proxy_db.sock"};
   int ret = start(3, argv);
   return ret;
}
 extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_android_client_testJNILib_stoplibrary(JNIEnv * je, jclass jc){
   library_signal_handler(SIGTERM);
   LOGE("CAlled library_signal_handler");
   return 1;
}
```

The library_signal_handler() is as follows:

```
    void
    library_signal_handler (int signo)
{
  int ret;
  __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "LIBRARY_MAIN", "Got signal %d \n", signo);
  switch (signo) {
 case SIGTERM:
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "LIBRARY_MAIN", "signal received sigterm\n");
  delete_all_alias_interface(alias_count);
  exit_stage_left();
  exit (0);
  break;
```

}

Kindly let me know how to overcome this.

Comment: Your question isn't making sense to me.  exit kills the current process.  that isn't what you want to do with your library stop call-  you want to kill whatever you started up, not yourself.  Which we can't tell you how to do because we don't see how/what you started, but in any case you wouldn't call exit to do so.

Comment: SO, what  would like to do is do everything exit() does manually. but not exit() the process. just cleaning up the resources.

Comment: exit normally does nothing except temrinate the current process.  It was never the right thing to do, although terminating the current process may have done what you wanted as a side effect.

Comment: the above library doesn't run as a separate process but runs from a thread call. So, when I call exit() it is terminating the entire parent android application too. Is there any way to terminate the library without terminating my application? I dont think exit() abort() works. both terminate my parent process i.e my android application.

Comment: Just end the thread? Hard to answer what to do when I don't have the code of what you're actually doing. But it looks like your library assumed it was going to be always running as long as the app was, did you may have some rewriting to do around removing that assumption

Comment: @GabeSechan: They are asking for a routine that performs only the clean-up functions (up to but not including process termination) of `exit` for a single thread: Close the files it opened, release memory it allocated, and so on. I doubt such a service exists. Files and other resources can be opened/allocated by one thread and handed off to another, so standard library routines would have no way of knowing what to close. The library must be designed to keep track of its own resources and provide its own routine to close/release them.

Comment: Your signal handler has serious issues.  You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  I suspect none of your function calls are async-signal-safe.  I **know** `exit()` is **not** safe.  For a signal handler running inside a JVM or JVM-like process, correct implementation of a signal handler is especially critical.